# How to see users in alphabetical order?

Tags: command-line

I want to know how to see the users by alphabetical order when using this command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

I get a list with a lot of names including mine but it's very long.
I want to order it alphabetically.

How I can do this?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Simplest:

```
cut -d: -f1  /etc/passwd | sort
```

To also view the user(s) information from the terminal type:

```
grep /home /etc/passwd | sort
```

The /home tells grep to drop any lines that do not contain the text /home thereby filtering out many lines that don't have information about users from the results of the command. In Ubuntu the user directories are located in the /home directory by default. This command will show several attributes for each user. The user attributes are:

```
username:password:UID:GID:info:home directory:shell
```

Comment: Depending on the situation, one might actually want to use `getent passwd` instead of the `passwd` file directly.

Comment: @GilBitton Don't thank people!  ;-) If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the abysmally small number now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you want just to sort only the names (after `cut`) use [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/601187/216503).

If you want to sort the `/etc/passwd` file alphabetically based on the usernames:

```
sort -t: -k1,1 /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the compgen command piped with sort:

```
compgen -u | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through python itself. Just run the below command on terminal.

```
$ python3 -c 'with open("/etc/passwd") as f:
    for i in sorted([x.split(":")[0] for x in f]):
        print(i)'
```

Note that the spaces before `for` was very important.